# MAMP Pro Appears to be missing site directory in document root path for site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp-pro

I have a client site that I need to work on in a local environment. I set the site up on my MAMP Pro server and imported the database, adding the client's user credentials and setting the site URL and homepage to "http://localhost:8888/client_website".

When I try to login with the URL "http://localhost:8888/client_website/wp-admin", I get a 500 error. Ditto if I use "http://localhost:8888/client_website/wp-login.php".

A look at the apache error logs shows multiple "File not found errors" for this site, with the requested path "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content".

I have developed dozens of websites on my MAMP server, but haven't seen this before.

Research on this yielded no useful information. Most of it is about resetting permalinks from inside WP-Admin. Trouble is, I can't access WP-Admin.

Actions Taken
There is no .htaccess file in the document root for this website, so disabling it won't help. I tried disabling the plugins directory, but that didn't help, either. I am hesitant to disable the client's theme because it could break the website (I've had this happen before when widgets and page builders are used to add content).

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The moral of this story is: When you've been a developer for a while and you see something strange like I did today, it could be something's corrupted in the WordPress files. In my case, it took me a total of about 6 hours to figure this out.

Unless you're positive it isn't something in WordPress, it might be a good idea to start over with a fresh install of WordPress sooner than later, especially if you know your server is configured correctly like mine was.

It helps to know how to work with PHPmyAdmin or similar tool to connect an existing database to the fresh WordPress install, but it saves hours of frustration trying to solve a problem that could be buried deep in a corrupted WordPress install.